# Error on running build command through npm run for reactjs project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, build, craco

Getting error on running "craco build"

Executing command:

`npm run dist`

It's the same error if I run `npm run build` from same folder.

Commands in package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run storybook:start",
    "dev": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "dist": "npm run build && del-cli build/*.* build/fonts",
    "test": "craco test",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
-----------------
```

Error Output

```
craco build

'craco' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

If I check the craco version by running `npm info craco version` then I receive `0.0.3`.
I am running node v8.0.0 and npm version is 5.0.0

I am on node v8.0.0 because of some project specific conditions.

Comment: I was getting same error when my node_modules folder was empty. Had to run yarn install.

Comment: Can you please try to install craco.. I executed "npm install @craco/craco" and it error went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this command

```
npm install @craco/craco --save
```

Comment: didn't work. it's already in package.json as "@craco/craco": "^6.1.1",, but it's still not recognized on Windows, only on Linux (`yarn start`)

Comment: I had it on my pakeage.json but still, I had to install it by issuing
    npm install @craco/craco --save

Comment: btw if you still have the same problem you can use the last version o tailwind it doesn't require craco